# (C++) Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler'. Did you compile with -rdynamic?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, glade

I'm new to C++ GUI programming with GTK+, and I'm having a issue with getting the signal handler for one of my buttons to work, upon compiling and running I receive the following warning. Does anyone know if I'm doing something incorrectly or missing something?

(Project Thoth:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'on_login_clicked'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

This is my cpp file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkEntry *e1;//textbox1
GtkEntry *e2;//textbox2
GtkEntry *e3;//textbox3

GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
GtkWidget *window;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "Unsaved 1.glade", NULL);
window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "Login"));

gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, window);

g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));
gtk_widget_show(window);
gtk_main();
cout << "Login window loaded";
return 0;
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT void  on_login_clicked()
{
printf("Request Detected\n");
GtkBuilder  *gtkBuilder;
GtkWidget *window;

gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "Unsaved 1.glade", NULL);

GtkEntry *e1;
GtkEntry *e2;
e1 = GTK_ENTRY( gtk_builder_get_object( gtkBuilder, "user1" ));
e2 = GTK_ENTRY( gtk_builder_get_object( gtkBuilder, "pass"));
gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, e1);
const char *home;
home = gtk_entry_get_text(e1);
cout << home;
}
```

and my glade file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="Login">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="default_width">400</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLayout" id="layout1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="Label">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Project Thoth
</property>
            <property name="angle">0.089999999999999997</property>
            <attributes>
              <attribute name="weight" value="bold"/>
            </attributes>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">156</property>
            <property name="y">14</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="user1">
            <property name="width_request">166</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">128</property>
            <property name="y">72</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Username: 
</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">121</property>
            <property name="y">52</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="pass">
            <property name="width_request">166</property>
            <property name="height_request">84</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">129</property>
            <property name="y">130</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label3">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Password:

</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">117</property>
            <property name="y">123</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Login</property>
            <property name="width_request">70</property>
            <property name="height_request">29</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">half</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_login_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">171</property>
            <property name="y">191</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="width_request">105</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">save info login ?</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">154</property>
            <property name="y">227</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSwitch" id="switch1">
            <property name="width_request">74</property>
            <property name="height_request">23</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">166</property>
            <property name="y">263</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

also for compiling i used the following flags

```
g++ -o "Project Thoth" main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0 )
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The message is giving a good suggestion: compile (actually link) with `-rdynamic` so compile your your code with:

```
 g++ -rdynamic  -o Project_Thoth -Wall -g main.cpp \
     $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0 )
```

BTW, I strongly recommend avoiding a space in your executable name. So `Project_Thoth` not `"Project Thoth"`. Also, don't forget to ask for warnings (with `-Wall` at least, perhaps also *add* `-Wextra`) and debug info (`-g`), which is very useful, notably to debug your program with `gdb` debugger (or to hunt memory leaks with `valgrind`).

Once the program is debugged, for benchmarking purposes, you might ask the compiler to optimize (so add `-O2`).

BTW, if you really want to use GTK with C++ (not just C), consider [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/). But you could code your GTK program in plain C99 (so no `cout`, but `printf`). And perhaps even consider a switch to [Qt](http://qt.io/) (another widget toolkit, in C++), if C++ is important to you.

If coding in C++ with GTK (not gtkmm), better declare as `extern "C"` *all* your GTK related code.

Comment: tried the different compile code and it had the same results. Im trying to save Qt as a last resort but if its easier i could move to gtkmm if it would save me problems down the line.

Comment: Perhaps `-rdynamic` should be given first, *before* `-o Project_Thoth`; BTW, if you code in C only (including your things, so `printf`, no `cout <<`) the compilation time would be faster since C++ code compiles slowly.

Comment: yea, i might just go with just using C because i know that works. Thank you for the help.